# Add CMS link to nav - Force Active State

Tags: css, magento, php

so i added this:

```
       <li class="level0 nav-1 parent"><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('blog')?>"><span><?php echo $this->__('Blog') ?></span></a></li>
```

and also tried this:

```
<li <?php if ($this->getRequest()->getAlias(Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS) == 'blog') { echo 'class="active"'; } else { echo 'class="blog"'; } ?>><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('blog')?>"><span><?php echo $this->__('Blog') ?></span></a></li>
```

in top.phtml. the link appears as expected.

but it does not display the active state of the button (the rectangle around the text) like the native links do.

here is the page:

http://pro-tools-training.com/new-magento2/index.php/

(click all the links in the nav and you'll see they all hold the active state except Blog)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the tip

I ended up using

```
getRequest()->getRouteName
```

many many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may be having PHP string comparison issues. Try using `strcmp`.

Also, try `getRequest()->getOriginalPathInfo()` instead of `getAlias()`